# Image overlapping DOM element border

Tags: css-float, overflow, border, overlap

I have a CSS problem. The floated image on my page overlaps the border of a paragraph.

The style looks like this:

```
.paragraph {
    border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.image {
    float:right;
}
```

**Here's the printscreen:**

[image]

**My question is: How to make it to behave like this?**

[image]

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudroljub/yx3o7z1v/1/). Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: you can wrap the content of .boxed inside a div of defined width, and float the div left while the img floats right...provided there is enough width in your parent container to hold both the div and the img

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few hours of researching, I found a very simple solution to this.

We just need to add one line of code to boxed paragraph:

`overflow: hidden;`

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudroljub/5f1Lpdj1/) for the result.

But thanks anyway!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At first change your HTML structure something like that

```
        <div class="left-content">
            <p class="boxed-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, ipsam, labore excepturi vel corporis libero facere impedit odio similique ipsa architecto mollitia dignissimos eveniet quaerat.</p>
            <p class="boxed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, ipsam, labore excepturi vel corporis libero facere impedit odio similique ipsa architecto mollitia dignissimos eveniet quaerat optio nulla totam voluptatem! Tenetur.</p>
        </div>


            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/240px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="HTML5_logo" class="image-right">

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, ipsam, labore excepturi vel corporis libero facere impedit odio similique ipsa architecto mollitia dignissimos eveniet quaerat optio nulla totam voluptatem! Tenetur.</p>
```

After that added this bellow CSS:

```
.boxed {
    padding:20px 40px;
    border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
 }
.image-right {
    float:right;
    width:150px;
}
.left-content {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 80%;
}
.boxed-1{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, http://jsfiddle.net/yx3o7z1v/11/.

I changed the width's to percentages and gave the box a width.

```
    .boxed {
    padding:20px 40px;
    border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    width:60%;
}
.image-right {
    float:right;
    width:20%;
    max-width:150px;
    position:relative;
}

p { position:relative; }
```